# Jenkins email-ext jelly script on Linux ignore html

Tags: jelly

I am using example html.jelly script for email-ext plugin on Jenkins under Windows 7 and i recieved normal email message. But the same html.jelly file on Jenkins under Linux show me in letter all html code as text. How to fix it?

html.jelly file - https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html.jelly

Thanks.